# Postgres HStore Errors - Unknown Operator

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, hstore

My ruby code:

```
Portfolio.where("data @> (:key => :value)",     :key => 'CSJ', :value => '0.1')
```

Generates the following SQL:

```
"SELECT \"portfolios\".* FROM \"portfolios\"  WHERE (data @> ('CSJ' => '0.1'))"
```

Comes up with this error:

```
Error: PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: unknown => unknown
LINE 1: ...olios".* FROM "portfolios"  WHERE (data @> ('CSJ' => '0.1'))
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "portfolios".* FROM "portfolios"  WHERE (data @> ('CSJ' => '0.1'))
```

Postgresql 9.1.4, Rails 3.2.7/8, using activerecord-postgres-hstore gem with the following in my model code:

```
serialize :data, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
```

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't know what => is...do you mean >= (greater than or equal to)?

Comment: @Jim: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html

Comment: Ah, thank you.  Hadn't seen that before.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed question and for including the versions you're working with from the start. Saves everyone a bunch of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't install the hstore extension in the database that Rails is using.

For example, if I say `select 'a' => 'b'` in one of my databases that doesn't have hstore, I get this:

```
=> select 'a' => 'b';
ERROR:  operator does not exist: unknown => unknown
LINE 1: select 'a' => 'b';
                   ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

But in another database that does have hstore installed, I get this:

```
=> select 'a' => 'b';
 ?column? 
----------
 "a"=>"b"
(1 row)
```

You need to do a [`create extension hstore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html) in your Rails database.

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming this.  I had originally considered this, and then decided it couldn't be the case as I HAD installed the extension.  But your note just made me remember that the last time I brought those databases in, I was lazy and regenerated them from a dump.  That must be the problem.... I'll accept before checking as I'm fairly sure now this is the problem!  Thx!

Comment: @Brandon: Might make sense to add a check for this to your test suite, `it 'should have had "create extension hstore" done in the database' do ...`.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Rails 3.2.13 and psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.4.  However, I have done the `create extension hstore`.  Help?

Comment: Disregard - syntax problem.  See: https://github.com/softa/activerecord-postgres-hstore

Comment: This issue solved it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707975/no-operator-matches-the-given-name-and-argument-types