# No operator matches the given name and argument type(s)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, postgresql-9.1, hstore

I set up my Rails 3.2.x app to use PostgreSQL HStore but I'm getting an error.
It looks like the hstore extension hasn't been picked up by the environment.
I already rebooted my machine, checked database extensions, etc.

When I try to execute:

```
User.where("settings @> (:key => :value)", :key => "setting_x", :value => "test")
```

I get an error: (`@>` is not recognized, i.e., extension `hstore` is not installed?)

```
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

My Rails application setup is:

Gemfile.rb:

```
gem 'activerecord-postgres-hstore'
```

Migration:

```
add_column :users, :settings, :hstore
execute "CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY users_gin_settings ON users USING GIN(settings)"
# can see the extenstion installed on my local dev psql database after this
```

`User` model:

```
serialize :settings, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
```

Dynamic `User` methods:

```
# metaprogramming: has_setting_x + instance.setting_x
%w[setting_x setting_y setting_z].each do |key|
attr_accessible key
    # doesn't work > throws error because of the @> operator
    scope "has_#{key}", lambda { |value| where("settings @> (? => ?)", key, value) }

    # works: can use instance.setting_x
    define_method(key) do
      settings && settings[key]
    end

    # works: can use instance.setting_x = "value"
    define_method("#{key}=") do |value|
      self.settings = (settings || {}).merge(key => value)
    end
end
```

---

Update 1:

This works when I talk directly to the PostgreSQL DB:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (settings @> hstore('setting_x','6D9Q7RO4SVWHXK86F'));
```

The [Hstore docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html) say:

```
The => operator is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Use the hstore(text, text) function instead.
```

So, from the look of it, my PostgreSQL database version (9.2.1) has already deprecated the `=>` notation.  It looks like I have more research ahead.

Comment: Don't add "Solution:" to your question. Add an answer, and when Stack Overflow times out, you can accept your answer.

Comment: @Sean Yes, tried that notation too.

Comment: +1 The edits and question are much better now. Stack Overflow likes the Wikipedia-style articles, so write clearly, concisely, and in full sentences. You'll notice my edit removed some abbreviations and improved grammar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html):

> The `=>` operator is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Use the `hstore(text, text)` function instead.

So from the look of it, my PG database version ( 9.2.1 ) has already deprecated the `=>` notation.
Working now both locally and on Heroku.

Example:

```
User.where("settings @> hstore(?,?)", "setting_x", key)
```